# Present view controller displays black screen

Tags: objective-c, ios, model-view-controller

I'm trying to present a view using code in Objective C, but all it comes up with is the title bar and a black screen.  This is the code I am using:

```
MoreByUserViewController *morebyuser = [[MoreByUserViewController alloc] initWithOwnerId:self.ImageOwner];
UINavigationController *navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:morebyuser];
[self presentModalViewController:navController animated:YES];
```

I am calling this from the startup view (hereby referred to as View 1) and the view I'm trying to load will be View 2.

I don't have View 2 included as #include or @class in View 1, do I need to?

Comment: I'd say there is a probably an issue with your custom init. Can we see its implementation?

Comment: I see this question pretty frequently. Just a guess? You didn't load the nib.

Comment: `- (id)initWithOwnerId:(NSString *)m_OwnerId
{
    userid = m_OwnerId;
    return self;
}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like Ryan and Dustin said, you probably are not loading the nib in that `initWithOwnerID` method. I would recommend initializing the view first, and then setting the `ownerID` as a property after.

```
MoreByUserViewController *morebyuser = [[MoreByUserViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MoreByUserViewController" bundle:nil];
[morebyuser setOwnerID:self.ImageOwner];
UINavigationController *navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:morebyuser];
[morebyuser release];
[self presentModalViewController:navController animated:YES];
[navController release];
```

Comment: Your code throws this: `Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Could not load NIB in bundle: 'NSBundle </Users/ianspence/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/6.0/Applications/EA041D16-336A-4EDC-A089-6297698DCCFD/Pickr Pro.app> (loaded)' with name 'MoreByUserViewController''`  I'm using ARC as well so I took out the release.

Comment: Did you put in the correct name for your xib file? And if you're using ARC then just take out those releases.

Comment: I was able to fix the problem by moving the view from the stoaryboard to a xib file and changing the code just a bit (removed the release and presented the ViewController rather than a navigation controller)